# Pass loop variable into function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, meteor, meteor-blaze

my problem is like this.
I want to find out if the current Route is active or not i am using zimme:active-route for this 
[https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/active-route][1]

So i am passing an Array to the template and running through it like this

```
{{#each users}}
   <a href="/member/{{this}}" class="tab-item {{isActiveRoute regex='*{{this}}'}}">
    {{this}}
   </a> 
{{/each}}
```

obviously the {{this}} in the regex is going to fail.
So my question is there a way to pass the thiss into the isActiveRoute function or do i have to come up with an workaround ?

Comment: isActiveRoute is your helper function right? So inside that you will get each users without passing them.

Comment: yeah its not my function it is from the active-route package ... i could do it by myself fore sure but i thought maybe there is a way to do it without writing my own helper function

Comment: you want to pass your current url to isActiveRoute function? then there is some other method to do the same.

Comment: no i want to pass {{this}} from the user array into the isActiveRoute regex param

Comment: instead {{this}} write helper function there ex. {{data}} and inside that helper function return the this. Don't know it will work or not?

Comment: jeah i know there is this kind of workaround. and i also used it but i just wanted to ask if there is  an way to express this inside of the template